# Subtract notification count without repeating

Tags: javascript

**Live Demo: https://effervescent-lokum-0a6ab0.netlify.app/**

I'm doing a frontend development challenge to practice which involves creating a notification panel similar to Facebook.

The notifications change color when clicked/read and the notification number reduces.

I would like to reduce the notification count when these notifications are clicked once but having difficulty finding a way to do this without the notification count reducing when it shouldn't ie when the user clicks the same element more than once and it still reduces the notification count.

How would I change the notification count number correctly?

Sorry about the amateur code!
Thanks

```
const noteItem = document.querySelectorAll("article");
const noteNumber = document.getElementById("notifs");
let newNumber = 0;
let currTarget = "";
let array = Array.from(noteItem);
let isNew = false;

console.log(`Array length is: ${noteItem.length}`);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", noteCheck);

function noteCheck() {
  console.log("noteCheck function called");
  noteNumber.textContent = noteItem.length;
  newNumber = noteItem.length;
  for (i = 0; i < noteItem.length; i++) {
    console.log(`This is the array: ${array}`);
    noteItem[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      console.log(e.currentTarget.classList);
      if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains("clicked")) {
        console.log("Clicked");
        e.currentTarget.setAttribute("notif-status", "old");
        e.currentTarget.classList.remove("clicked");
        e.currentTarget.setAttribute("disabled", "");
        array.pop();
        noteNumber.textContent = array.length;
      } else {
        e.currentTarget.classList.remove("new-item");
        e.currentTarget.classList.remove("new");
        e.currentTarget.classList.add("clicked");
      }
    });
    console.log(noteItem[i]);
    if (noteItem[i].classList.contains("new")) {
      noteItem[i].classList.add("new-item");
      noteItem[i].setAttribute("notif-status", "new");
    }
  }
}
```

`

I have tried several ways of getting this to work.
Tried adding attribute and to check if attribute exists, using an array and array.pop() to represent when user reads notification to pop one object and then output array.length, adding classes to the notifications etc. These all work to a certain extent in that they change the state of the notification element but the end result doesn't output the real value of how many notifications are left after clicking/reading and it's easily manipulated/doesn't work/isn't feasible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short snippet that should indicate an easy way to do this.

Your code is a bit messy, so I didn't use it to analyse what you are doing wrong, instead I've provided an example of my own. It only takes a couple lines of code.

```js
function noteCheck(element) {

  // remove 'unread' if element is present
  if(element) {
    element.classList.remove('unread');
  }

  // update notification counter
  // this sets the notification-count to how many posts remain with the "unread" class.
  document.getElementById("notification-count").innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#notification-list .unread').length;
  
}

// initial counter check
noteCheck();
```

```css
.unread {
  background-color: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="notification-count" style="color:red;">0</div>

<div id="notification-list">
<div class="notification unread" onclick="noteCheck(this)">Lorum ipsum</div>
<div class="notification unread" onclick="noteCheck(this)">Lorum ipsum</div>
<div class="notification unread" onclick="noteCheck(this)">Lorum ipsum</div>
<div class="notification unread" onclick="noteCheck(this)">Lorum ipsum</div>
<div class="notification unread" onclick="noteCheck(this)">Lorum ipsum</div>
</div>
```